# gcc/clang usage of restrict keyword for local variables and struct fields

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Can't figure out how to convince gcc/clang that my pointers don't intersect; for what I see, it looks like `restrict` is only honored if specified in function arguments and ignored otherwise. Here is my code:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__cplusplus)
#define restrict __restrict
#endif

struct s {
    int sz;
    int *a;
    int *b;
};

struct s_r {
    int sz;
    int *restrict a;
    int *restrict b;
};

void foo_dumb_struct(struct s *s, int c) {
    int sz = s->sz;
    for(int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
        s->a[i] = s->b[0] + c;
    }
}

void foo_restricted_arrays(int sz,
        int *restrict a, int *restrict b,
        int c) {
    for(int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
        a[i] = b[0] + c;
    }
}

void foo_restricted_struct(struct s_r *s, int c) {
    int sz = s->sz;
    for(int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
        s->a[i] = s->b[0] + c;
    }
}

void foo_restricted_subcall(struct s *s, int c) {
    foo_restricted_arrays(s->sz, s->a, s->b, c);
}

void foo_restricted_cast(struct s *s, int c) {
    int sz = s->sz;
    int *restrict a = s->a;
    int *restrict b = s->b;
    for(int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
        a[i] = b[0] + c;
    }
}
```

Icc is fine with this code, but gcc/clang generates re-read of `b[0]` on each iteration for `foo_restricted_struct` and `foo_restricted_cast`, for all architectures I could test with godbolt. Any time it is used in function arguments (including nested functions or C++ lambdas) it is fine and extra load is removed. https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html suggests that it actually worked as I want it to, but I'm not sure their gcc wasn't customized for cell specifically.

Is my usage of restrict wrong, or gcc/clang only implements restrict for function arguments and nothing else?

Comment: gcc has never been very good at optimization opportunities based on `restrict`

Comment: @M.M I don't see that; do you happen to have any examples? For all I see, when it doesn't ignore restrict (so in my case only in function args) it behaves the same way as local vars which addresses wasn't spilled. Basically the same reason why I copied `s->sz` into local var. Looks like clang's LLVM IR output uses the same `noalias` for both locals and restrict, once again only if used in function args - I don't suppose actual optimisation is handled differently.

Comment: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/65acf43270ea2894dffa0d0b292b92402f80c8cb/lib/CodeGen/CGCall.cpp#L2415 is the only place in clang I could find that actually uses restrict to emit noalias, so only funciton args. No luck with gcc yet.

Comment: Relevant bug report for GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60712  -- "Only restrict on parameters is implemented".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for what I see, it looks like `restrict` is only honored if specified in function arguments

That characterization sounds like you think `restrict` qualification carries some kind of *obligation* to optimize more aggressively.  That explicitly is not the case:

> A translator is free to ignore any or all aliasing implications of uses of restrict.

(C standard, paragraph 6.7.3.1/6)

I do grant that it is a bit surprising that a compiler that takes advantage of `restrict` qualification to perform additional optimizations in some cases would not do the same in other, similar cases, but that does not imply that either the code or the compiler is in any way wrong. (But do bear in mind Eric's observation about restrict-qualified structure members).  Also, however, the examples presented may not all be as similar to each other as you suppose.

> Is my usage of restrict wrong, or gcc/clang only implements restrict for function arguments and nothing else?

Although the standard defines semantics for `restrict`-qualified block-scoped variables, they cannot really be used for much.  Restrict qualification is a means to move some responsibility for dependency analysis from compiler to programmer, but the programmer has no more information to bring to bear than the compiler already has in a case such as the `foo_restricted_cast()` example.  I'd say that yes, your usage there is (semantically) wrong, because you have no sound basis on which to make the implicit guarantee that local variables `a` and `b` will not alias each other.  I rate GCC's and Clang's behavior prudent and appropriate in that light, and ICC's somewhat rash.

As for `restrict`-qualified structure members, I disagree with the other answer's assertion that no semantics are defined for them.  It is true that the identifiers of structure members are not "ordinary identifiers", but the wording of the standard's definition of `restrict` semantics seems to be specifically crafted with a view toward covering structure members via the declarations of the ordinary identifiers of structure objects containing them.  The language can certainly be read that way, and it is more than usually fraught if it is meant otherwise.

Thus, I think that the case of `foo_restricted_struct()` has well-defined semantics, and furthermore that `icc` is justified in taking advantage of the non-aliasing assertions conveyed by the `restrict` qualification of the argument structure's members, just as if they were direct function parameters.  It is impossible for me to say why `gcc` and `Clang` do not also take advantage of the optimization options that proceed, but again, they have no obligation to do so.

On the other hand, `foo_restricted_subcall()` exhibits a semantic problem similar to the one in `foo_restricted_cast()`.  I suppose that there is an outside chance that it is for that reason that GCC and/or Clang avoids more aggressively optimizing `foo_restricted_struct()`, which `foo_restricted_subcall()` calls with a semantically problematic argument.  Probably, though, these compilers just don't perform a deep enough analysis to see the optimization opportunity in this case.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware that ignoring a keyword is standard-compliant; my question is about specific compilers. In a way, my only problem is I can't get any case said compilers *ever* respect restrict outside of function arguments, which leads me to believe it isn't implemented there (but again, an old article says it was, may be for some reason it was removed), but it appears source of gcc or clang (thankfully not llvm itself) are the only places I could find answers. What we seem to disagree upon is that compiler needs to perform dependency analysis and not just go full "ok thanks for the tip"

Comment: To clarify - it does need to perform dependency analysis *after* that, whithin function or block (which standard seems to give no distinction on that aspect). Calling side (please correct me if I'm wrong standard-wise) don't even technically have to have restrict in function declarations (but logically needs to be aware, of course), functions are optimised independently without considering outside call will violate specified restrictions (and this is why we have `-Wrestrict` to help with calling side checks).

Answer (score 2):

`restrict` is not defined by the C standard for members of structures.

The formal definition of `restrict` in 6.7.3.1 begins with “Let **D** be a declaration of an ordinary identifier…”

6.2.3 1 defines defines “ordinary identifiers“ to exclude members of structures or unions:

> … Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> — *label names* (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
>
> — the *tags* of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any of the
>   keywords **struct**, **union**, or **enum**);
>
> — the *members* of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the member via the **.** or
>   **->** operator);
>
> — all other identifiers, called *ordinary identifiers* (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

Footnote 126 in 6.7.2.1 explicitly tells us structure members are not ordinary identifiers:

> A structure or union cannot contain a member with a variably modified type because member names are not ordinary identifiers as defined in 6.2.3.

Comment: Yet half a page later the same standard gives example of struct with restricted field. Ok, let's assume it is bogus (but which part is unclear), but what about just local pointers taken from struct?

Comment: I was about to post very similar comments earlier today, but I have come to think that the analysis is incorrect.  It is necessary to consider a more complete quotation: "Let D be a declaration of an ordinary identifier that provides a means of designating an object P as a restrict-qualified pointer to type T".  If D is the declaration of an object of a structure type that has a restrict-qualified pointer as a member, then it designates that subobject as a restrict-qualified pointer, even though that sub-object is not itself designated by an ordinary identifier.